# Continuous Backup Testing?

Tags: linux, backup, automated-testing

Is there any software/setup that allows for automatic backup testing daily? by testing i mean test deployment, check setup post deploy warn on bad result? would be nice to use some kind of VM to deploy into. The Platform is Linux

The idea is that the software would redeploy to a test machine, and validate the restore :)

Answer (score 0):

Acronis True Image / Backup & Recovery has the option to validate the the backups once they've been created for consistency - and they have Linux flavours as well. You can schedule a recovery item to test the deployment of your image to ensure it works properly.

[http://www.acronis.com](http://acronis.com)

I would still run test restores every once in a while to ensure the integrity of your backup and they restore properly though.

Comment: See Edit Above for clarification

Comment: Validating a backup and Testing a backup are completely different. Just because you have a valid copy of *something*, doesn't mean that *something* is enough to restore from.

Comment: so you're saying that i've backed up my webserver + the databases and nginx configurations etc etc.. but there isn't anything that would test a deployment and check all the services come back to life?

Comment: I'm confused - isn't the automated recovery of an image what you're looking for? You can schedule the restore job and have the archive validated before the restore job starts. Once the job is done you can power on the VM to ensure it works